# ExpiresByType with both a wildcard and a specific mime type

Tags: apache, mod-expires

If I have Apache set to use:

```
ExpiresByType image/* A3600
ExpiresByType image/png A7200
```

Presumably, inverting this would make all images cache for one hour because the wildcard is last:

```
ExpiresByType image/png A7200
ExpiresByType image/* A3600
```

Images will default to one hour expiry, but will my PNG files be cached for one hour or two? Or to rephrase the question, does mod_expires continue processing rules after it finds the first match?  I can't find a definitive answer to this either on SO or in the documentation, or even in examples online. Is this likely to be consistent across HTTPd versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have observed that on Apache 2.4.6

```
ExpiresByType image/* A3600
ExpiresByType image/png A7200
```

and

```
ExpiresByType image/png A7200
ExpiresByType image/* A3600
```

both result in the same thing: The expiry date for PNG files is set to two hours and the expiry date for other image files to one hour, i.e. **the more specific ExpiresByType directive wins, regardless of order**.

The changelogs indicate that this behaviour should be consistent from ancient Apache versions through to the latest release.

Comment: funny coincidence that i am facing this same problem one year later to the day :)

Comment: Spooky. We ended up not chancing it and going for image/* and explicit ExpiresByType for text/html etc. Looking at the source / changelogs like you did is the right answer. Thanks @Sam!